# Dividing a file in R and automatically creating notepad files

Tags: r

I have a file which is like this :

```
"1943" 359 1327 "t000000" 8
"1944" 359 907 "t000000" 8
"1946" 359 472 "t000000" 8
"1947" 359 676 "t000000" 8
"1948" 326 359 "t000000" 8
"1949" 359 585 "t000000" 8
"1950" 359 1157 "t000000" 8
"2460" 275 359 "t000000" 8
"2727" 22 556 "t000000" 8
"2730" 22 676 "t000000" 8
"479" 17 1898 "t0000000" 5
"864" 347 720 "t000s" 12
"3646" 349 691 "t000s" 7
"6377" 870 1475 "t000s" 14
"7690" 566 870 "t000s" 14
"7691" 870 2305 "t000s" 14
"8120" 870 1179 "t000s" 14
"8122" 44 870 "t000s" 14
"8124" 870 1578 "t000s" 14
"8125" 206 870 "t000s" 14  
"8126" 870 1834 "t000s" 14
"6455" 1 1019 "t000t" 13
"4894" 126 691 "t00t" 9
"4896" 126 170 "t00t" 9
"560" 17 412 "t0t" 7
"130" 65 522 "tq" 18
"1034" 17 990 "tq" 10
"332" 3 138 "ts" 2
"2063" 61 383 "ts" 5
"2089" 127 147 "ts" 11
"2431" 148 472 "ts" 15
"2706" 28 43 "ts" 21
.....................
```

The first column is the random row number ( got after some sorting that I needed ), the fourth column contains the pattern for which I actually want different notepad files.

What I want is that I get individual notepad files named for example, f1.txt,f2.txt,f3.txt...containing all the rows for a value in column 4. For example, I get a different file for "t000000" and then a different one for "t000s" and then a seperate one for "t00t" and so on...

I did this,

```
list2env(split(sort, sort[,4]),envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Here sort is my text file name of data set and 3 is that column.
And then I can use the write.table command, but since my file is huge, I get around 100's of files like that and doing write.table manually like that is very difficult. Is there any way I can automate it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the excellent data.table package:

```
library(data.table)

# get your source file
the_file <- fread('~/Desktop/file.txt') #replace with your file path

# vector of unique values of column 4 & the roots of your output filename
fl_names <- unique(the_file$V4)

# dump all the relevant subsets to files
for (f in fl_names) write.table(the_file[V4==f, ], paste0(f, '.txt'), row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: This doesnt work at all. It just creates two variables f1_names and f having NULL.

Comment: Hmm, works nice and quick on my machine. I see you typed f1_names and not fl_names (numeral one not lower case L) above. Perhaps there are other typos in the version you tried? Do you get a 12x5 data.table with column names V1 through V5 after the fread() step?

Comment: @arvi1000, I think they are mistakenly looking for the files in their workspace, not in their working directory.

Comment: No, I just copied your commands. So, no chance of typo( I just typed it here incorrectly, i.e. f1 ) and yes I got the table containing 5 columns after the fread step.

Comment: Okay, in that case (if you using the same source data as the example above) you should get fl_names being a character vector of length 6. The final value of f after the last line completes should be 'ts', and you should see 6 files with extension '.txt' in your working directory. If you get fl_names = NULL instead, then you probably haven't read the data into the object called 'the_file'.

Comment: I removed that error. However, in the laststep it shows the error:
`Error in `[.data.frame`(the_file, V4 == f, ) : object 'V4' not found`.

Comment: V4 should be the name (the current version of) data.table assigns by default to the 4th column. What do you get when you run: names(the_file)

Comment: I get it as "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5"

Answer (score 1):

You've already figured out `split`, but instead of `list2env`, which will make more work for you just use `lapply`:

```
# Generally confusing to name a data.frame 
# the same as a common function!
X <- split(sort, sort[, 4])  
invisible(lapply(names(X), function(y) 
  write.csv(X[[y]], file = paste0(y, ".csv"))))
```

---

Proof of concept:

```
Dir <- getwd()                # Won't be necessary in your actual script
setwd(tempdir())              # I just don't want my working directory filled
list.files(pattern=".csv")    # with random csv files, so I'm using tempdir()
# character(0)                # Note that there are no csv files presently
X <- split(sort, sort[, 4])   # You've already figured this step out
## invisible is just so you don't have to see an empty list
## printed in your console. The rest is pretty straightforward
invisible(lapply(names(X), function(y)
 write.csv(X[[y]], file = paste0(y, ".csv"))))
list.files(pattern=".csv")    # Check that the files are there
# [1] "t000000.csv"  "t0000000.csv" "t000s.csv"    "t000t.csv"   
# [5] "t00t.csv"     "t0t.csv"      "tq.csv"       "ts.csv" 
setwd(Dir)                    # Won't be necessary for your actual script
```

Comment: @user3797829, Sure. Just substitute `write.csv` with your favorite `write.table` settings.

Comment: Hey, I did this: `X <- split(the_file, the_file[, 4])`
`invisible(lapply(names(X), function(y)` 
    `write.table(X[[y]], file = paste0(y, ".txt"))))` 
But nothing happened. Is there anything wrong with this? ( the_file is the name of the file I used )

Comment: @user3797829, you're trying to write this to your working directory, right? (A folder somewhere on your computer.) `getwd()` will tell you where your working directory is and where the files should be found. `list.files(pattern=".txt")` will show you (in R) the names of all the txt files in your working directory.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that from the explanation but what I am trying to say is the original file, didnt get split up. There are no new files with the names such as t000000.txt. Nothing like that took place.

Comment: @user3797829, both these answers work for me. You need to provide more detail about what's not working. You're saying that after running the `list.files()` step I mentioned, you don't see any new files in your working directory? You *did* skip the lines about `setwd(tempdir())`, right?